# Removing unwanted vertical space between 2 divs

Tags: css, html, layout

I'm having trouble aligning `#totalAvailable2` to the bottom of `#container2`.
I got it to work with `#container1` and `#totalAvailable`, as you'll see in the jsfiddle below.

JSFiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7rWJr/2

**HTML**

```
<div id = "outerContainer">
    <ul>
        <li id="firstList">
            <div id="container1">
                <div id = containter1Header>Mobile Chef</div>
                <div id = "innerContainer">
                    <!-- Content goes here -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="totalAvailable">Total:<span id = "span"></span></div>
        </li>
        <li id="secondList">
            <div id="container2">
                <div id = containter2Header>Mobile Chef</div>
                <div id = "innerContainer">
                    <!-- Content goes here -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <div id="totalAvailable2">Total:<span id = "span2"></span></div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/*********************************/
/* BEGIN OUTER CONTAINER STYLING*/
/*********************************/

#outerContainer ul li {
    list-style: none;
}
#outerContainer ul li#firstList {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
}
#outerContainer ul li#SecondList {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin:0px;
}

/*********************************/
/* END OUTER CONTAINER STYLING*/
/*********************************/


/*********************************/
/* BEGIN INNER CONTAINER STYLING*/
/*********************************/

#innerContainer {
    margin-left: 30px;
}
#totalAvailable {
    height: 50px;
    width:  490px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 23px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    font-family: arial;
    border-width: 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: gray;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border-top-style: none;
}
#totalAvailable2 {
    height: 50px;
    width:  490px;;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 23px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    font-family: arial;
    border-width: 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: gray;
    display: inline-block;
    border-top-style: none;
    margin-left: 40px
}

/*********************************/
/* END INNER CONTAINER STYLING*/
/*********************************/


#container1 {
    background: url("http://www.anytimeinteractive.com/dev/test/images/bgdk.jpg");;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    border-width: 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: gray;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 600px;
    width: 500px;
    overflow: auto;
}

#container2{
    height: 600px;
    width: 500px;
    background: url("http://www.anytimeinteractive.com/dev/test/images/bgdk.jpg");;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    border-width: 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: gray;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: **UPDATED JSFIDDLE:**   http://jsfiddle.net/7rWJr/2/

Comment: Technically speaking, this isn't an issue with alignment. It's an issue with removing unwanted vertical space between two elements.

Comment: I removed most of the code from the question that wasn't related to the problem. This may make it easier for others to read and understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kwLMP/)

**HTML changes**

```
    <!-- Moved this div inside the li tag -->
    <div id="totalAvailable2">Total:<span id = "span2"></span></div>
</li>
```

The `#totalAvailable2` `div` was directly inside the `ul`. The only type of element that's allowed to be directly inside a `ul` is a `li`. That part of the HTML was invalid and might cause problems in some browsers. I'm guessing that you meant to put it inside the `li`, like you did for `#totalAvailable`.

**CSS changes**

```
#outerContainer ul li#secondList {   /* SecondList -> secondList */
    overflow: hidden;   /* added */
    ...
}
#container2 {
    /* display: inline-block; */   /* removed */
    ...
}
#totalAvailable2 {
    /* display: inline-block; */   /* removed */
    ...
}
```

There was a typo in the CSS: `#secondList` was instead `#SecondList`.

After that and the above HTML change, removing `inline-block` from `#container2` and `#totalAvailable2` and adding `overflow:hidden;` to `#secondList` seemed to fix it.

### The use of overflow: hidden

If there are columns, and all but one of them are floated, adding `overflow: hidden` to the non-floated column prevents the content from wrapping around below the floated columns (the way a paragraph of text wraps around a floated image).

As a side effect of this, if the non-floated column also has a width of 100% (explicitly or by default), `overflow: hidden` will cause it to fill all remaining space in the parent container, without overlapping the floated columns. There's no need to add a horizontal margin to the non-floated column, to prevent it from overlapping. This makes it much easier to create variable-width columns.

Here's an [article](http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/#making-room-for-floats) that explains how this works.

Comment: Works great, thanks Matt.  Everything makes sense except `overflow:hidden` on `secondList`.  Can you explain why this works?

Comment: @DsoNce: I updated the answer with an explanation of how `overflow: hidden` is used.

Answer (score 0):

```
#container2{
height: 600px;
width: 500px;
background: url("images/bgdk.jpg");;
margin-left: 40px; <----------- Problem here. Set to 10px to fix.
margin-top: 40px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
border-width: 4px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: gray;
display: inline-block;
overflow: auto;
}
```

In `container1` the margin-left is set to 10px.

Currently you have:

```
container1{
   margin-left: 10px;
}
container2{
   margin-left: 40px;
}
```

So of course container two is going to be shifted out of alignment by 30px.

I would do this with a class. What's the point of doing ids for two identical containers? It only duplicates the CSS and thus you find yourself in predicaments like this.

Comment: Changed it to [margin-left] to [10px] and it shifts to the right. Further out of alignment with the [container2].

Comment: Do you want them both at 40 or both at 10?

Comment: Sorry ... I'll try to clarify.  I'm hoping to have 2 columns. In column 1, I'd like to have [container1] stack vertically on top of [totalAvailable].  Then, in column 2 I'd like [container2] to stack vertically on top op [totalAvailable2]. Check out the output at: jsfiddle.net/7rWJr/2       --   Thank you!